# Arity mismatch error message in pagefactory

Tags: java, selenium

I am doing practising in homedepot.com
right now I have this kind of question getting stuck,the error messege is:
 **"Arity mismatch: Step Definition 'StepsTestCase.SearchShoppingStep.click_close_button_in_add_to_cart_window(WebDriver) in file:/C:/Users/Administrator/git/MavenProject/target/classes/' with pattern [^Click close button in add to cart window$] is declared with 1 parameters. However, the gherkin step has 0 arguments []. 
      Step: When Click close button in add to cart window"**

My code in stepdefinition:

public class SearchShoppingStep {

```
@Given("^Input 'Hammer' in search bar$")

public void input_Hammer_in_search_bar() throws Throwable {
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Webdrivers//chromedriver.exe/");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.navigate().to("https://www.homedepot.com");
    ShoppingPage SP = PageFactory.initElements(driver, ShoppingPage.class);
   ShoppingPage.SearchBar.sendKeys("Hammer");
}

@Given("^Click search button$")
public void click_search_button() throws Throwable {
 ShoppingPage.SearchBtn.click();
}

@When("^Verify 'Husky_(\\d+)_oz\\. Fiberglass_Claw_Hammer' is displayed$")
public void verify_Husky___oz_Fiberglass_Claw_Hammer_is_displayed(int arg1) throws Throwable {
     if(ShoppingPage.Husky16oz.isDisplayed() )      
        {
             System.out.println("'Husky 16 oz. Fiberglass Claw Hammer' displayed.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("'Husky 16 oz. Fiberglass Claw Hammer' not displayed.");
        }
}

@When("^Click add to cart button of \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void click_add_to_cart_button_of(String arg1) throws Throwable {
    ShoppingPage.AddtoCartBtn.click();
}

@When("^Click close button in add to cart window$")
public void click_close_button_in_add_to_cart_window(WebDriver driver) throws Throwable {
      driver.switchTo().frame(ShoppingPage.IframeXpath);
    ShoppingPage.ClsBtnOfIframe.click();
}

@Then("^go back to homepage$")
public void go_back_to_homepage() throws Throwable {
   ShoppingPage.HomeDepotLogoBtn.click();
}

@Then("^verify  selected items in cart is displayed$")
public void verify_selected_items_in_cart_is_displayed() throws Throwable {
    String quantity =
            ShoppingPage.IteminMycart.getText();
                    int n = Integer.parseInt(quantity);
                    if(n==1) {
                            System.out.println("1 item is selected");
                    }else {
                            System.out.println("Check the cart");
                    }
}

@Given("^Input 'Bug_Spray' in search bar$")
public void input_Bug_Spray_in_search_bar() throws Throwable {
    ShoppingPage.SearchBar.clear();
    ShoppingPage.SearchBar.sendKeys("Bug Spray");
}

@When("^click searh button$")
public void click_searh_button() throws Throwable {
   ShoppingPage.SearchBtn.click();
}

@Then("^verify 'Repel (\\d+)\\.(\\d+) oz\\. Aerosol Sportsmen Max Insect Repellent' is displayed$")
public void verify_Repel_oz_Aerosol_Sportsmen_Max_Insect_Repellent_is_displayed(int arg1, int arg2) throws Throwable {
     if(ShoppingPage.RepelInsectRepellent.isDisplayed() )      
        {
             System.out.println("''Repel 6.5 oz. Aerosol Sportsmen Max Insect Repellent' is displayed.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("'Repel 6.5 oz. Aerosol Sportsmen Max Insect Repellent' is not displayed.");
        }
}

@Then("^go back to home page$")
public void go_back_to_home_page() throws Throwable {
      ShoppingPage.HomeDepotLogoBtn.click();
}
```

}

and the feature file:

@Searchitem1
  Scenario: SearchItem1
    Given Input 'Hammer' in search bar
    And Click search button
    When Verify 'Husky_16_oz. Fiberglass_Claw_Hammer' is displayed
    And Click add to cart button of "Husky_16oz"
    When Click close button in add to cart window
    Then go back to homepage
    And verify  selected items in cart is displayed

it stops in "**When Click close button in add to cart window**"

any ideas?Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the parameter WebDriver driver in the below method. You have no mention of an argument in your feature file. So you can't have a parameter in this method.

```
@When("^Click close button in add to cart window$")
public void click_close_button_in_add_to_cart_window(WebDriver driver) throws Throwable {
      driver.switchTo().frame(ShoppingPage.IframeXpath);
    ShoppingPage.ClsBtnOfIframe.click();
}
```